# Data Gridview Auto increment

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

Can anyone modify this code for me.

```
        Private Sub DGV_Items_CellClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGV_Items.CellClick
    Dim rowIndex As Integer = e.RowIndex
    Dim celval As String
    With DGV_Items
        If DGV_Items.Rows.Count > 1 Then
            celval = .Rows(.RowCount - 2).Cells(.ColumnCount - 4).Value
        End If
    End With

    If rowIndex = 0 Then

        cmd = New SqlCommand("Select S_No from Orders where S_No = (Select MAX(S_No) from Orders)", con)
        If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While dr.Read()
            result = dr.Item("S_No")
        End While
        dr.Close()
        If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then con.Close()
        DGV_Items.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value = (result + 1).ToString

    ElseIf DGV_Items.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value Is Nothing Then

        If rowIndex > 0 Then
            DGV_Items.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value = celval + 1
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I don't want the ID to be assigned unless one of the cell (cell(1) or cell(2)) contain value(string).

I tried my best to solve it but was unable and to the current stage it took 2 days which I think isn't bad to write such code.

Thank you.

Comment: If you are providing the code for it, there is nothing auto increment about it.  AutoIncrement values are provided by the database.

Comment: You are right Plutonix that Auto Increment values are provided by database, but there are methods to only display those incremented values to user. In some cases like mine I'm going to store more than one entry to database at a time, so the first one would be provided by database while others can't because the value before them won't exist in database.

Comment: Why would the user care about the identity value - do you even know the ID SO used for your account? Your increment method is not always going to get the same value as the one actually used by an AI PK.

Comment: You should try my code I made that logic of expressing the auto incremented values in datagridview but there are some other issues that I want to be solved in this code.

Comment: Because there would be edit and delete panels so that user can memorize the id and would be able to edit and delete by using that id.

Comment: In the code that I mentioned above that auto increment is AI PK.